# Android : Touch and an edit text is created

Tags: android, android-layout

I have do the following :
1.User touches a point in an image ->
2.And he get to write something to it .

How can i do that in android ?

Comment: first read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlImageContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etImageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivPic"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ivPic"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/ivPic"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then inside code

```
RelativeLayout rlImageContainer = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.rlImageContainer);
final EditText etImageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etImageText);
rlImageContainer.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
 etImageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
```